# Exchange Authorization Code for Access Token for SPA application

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

I have a SPA React app with Rails BE. I'm using https://github.com/anthonyjgrove/react-google-login to generate the `code` with accessType offline. This generates a code successfully and I'm able to get that back.

Now I'm trying to use this code to make a POST request to https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token using POSTMAN

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'code=4/0AX4XfWhUc8IC12kr1115g71111' \
--data-urlencode 'redirect_uri=urn:ief:wg:oauth:2.0:oob' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=x.apps.googleusercontent.com' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=secret' \
--data-urlencode 'scope=' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=authorization_code'
```

This looks right in terms of using the https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground. It works here.

However, when I try to make a request through curl or HttParty it fails. I'm not sure if this is happening because I'm getting the code from an SPA app then using my a BE app to make the other request.

[EDIT]
I should mention I tried multiple different redirect_uri. localhost:3000, 3003.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to make the Token API call from the SPA app. I was able to make a successful request.

I need to rethink how to organize and make calls.